# How to get multiple fields from sql database and displaying them into different html statements

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm getting data from my database, i want to show one field into a dropdown menu and the rest(according to the selected user in the dropdown menu) in a paragraph below it as im trying to do in the code below, what is missing please?

```
<div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-container w3-text-black">

<?php
    echo "<select name='users' id='users' placeholder='Employee'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='w3-container'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-briefcase fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>". $row['department'] ."</p>";
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-home fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>Malta</p>";
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-envelope fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>user@email.com</p>";
    }

?>
      <hr>
```

I have now tried with a foreach loop, but i need it to only display the data of the selected user. How can i do that? (code below)

```
    <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-container w3-text-black">

<?php
    $my_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo "<select name='users' id='users' placeholder='Employee'>";
        foreach($my_rows as $row) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        echo"</div>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo"<div class='w3-container'>";
        foreach($my_rows as $row) {

            echo "<p value='" . $row['id'] ."'><i class='fa fa-briefcase fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>". $row['department'] ."</p>";
            echo "<p><i class='fa fa-home fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>Malta</p>";
            echo "<p><i class='fa fa-envelope fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>user@email.com</p>";
            }

                    ?>
        <hr>
```

Comment: What is the current result of your code?  How does it differ from the desired result?

Comment: right now im only getting the dropdown menu with the db values, so thats working. Now i want the paragraph below it to display the other fields in the db according to the selected value in the dropdown menu

Comment: *"what is missing please?"* ... if you're trying to update the data in the paragraphs based on what's selected in the dropdown, then what's missing is a basic understanding of how [server/client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) web applications actually work. PHP runs on the server, nothing you do in the HTML (client) can affect it in any way... unless you make another request to the server - possibly using Ajax.

Comment: Then you're going to need to implement ajax to fetch the related values based on the selected option.  Do some research on that (there are plenty of questions/answers here, plus off-site tutorials/guides) and make an attempt.  If you get stuck, feel free to update your question with your attempted code and the result.

Comment: Your first while loop comsumes ALL the resultset so the second query has nothing left to process

Comment: How can i change that RiggsFolly ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` twice which will consume the entire resultset, use `mysqli_fetch_all()` to get an array of results, then use a `foreach` loop over those results instead of a `while` loop.

```php
<div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-container w3-text-black">

<?php
    //Safely get the currently selected user, assuming GET for now
    $currently_selected_user_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'users', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    $my_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "<select name='users' id='users' placeholder='Employee'>";
    foreach($my_rows as $row) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='w3-container'>";
    foreach($my_rows as $row) {
        //Using the weak equality but ideally this would be !==
        if($currently_selected_user_id != $row['id']){
            continue;
        }
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-briefcase fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>". $row['department'] ."</p>";
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-home fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>Malta</p>";
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-envelope fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-large w3-text-teal'></i>user@rhinocerosltd.com</p>";
    }

?>
      <hr>
```

Comment: " Now i want the paragraph below it to display the other fields in the db according to the selected value in the dropdown menu".  I don't think OP wants to display _all_ the results in the second section.  Only the result for the selected user.

Comment: Yes i want to display only the data of the selected user, not all. But thanks for the reply. I believe i will still need to use a foreach anyway so i can use the array more than once.

Comment: To the OP, this has been updated to include a check assuming that you've got form logic that submits the `<select>` field using a GET. @PatrickQ, thanks, I didn't realize that the question was a two-parter!

Comment: only the dropdown menu is being displayed with that code

Comment: @JulianZahra, try selecting a user. You'll need to include actual `<form>` code and probably JavaScript to auto-submit on select.